# eventlistner in table each row only trigger last row

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm writing a table allow user click table row and show the hidden rows.
I use addEventListener with loop to allow each table row call the hidden rows under the row.
For example:

```
row A 
row B
```

after clicking row A, hidden rows will show under row A and above row B

```
row A
hidden row 1
hidden row 2
row B
```

however, my code will always and only trigger the last row. If there are 15 rows in the table could click and show rows. Only the hidden rows of 15th row will show. No matter I click 1st row or 15th row, the web always show the 15th row.

```
                        var id = "";
                        var count = 1;
                        var table = document.getElementById("header_table");
                        for (var i = 0; i < r.length - 1; i++) {
                            id = 'detail_' + i;
                            console.log(id);
                            table.rows[count].addEventListener('click', function () {
                                console.log("clicking row " + i);
                                $("." + id).toggle();
                            });
                            count = count + 6;
                        }
```

Comment: it would be helpful, if you can add a working snippet off-course with this bug. Try adding something like jfiddle, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, I solved my question. I should bind the parameter into the function.

[Reference: Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my program.
I needed to add an event listener to each row of a table, so I made a for-each loop of the rows and added the event listener:

```
for (var r of table.childNodes[0].childNodes) {
  r.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // Do Stuff To Row 'R'
    for (var c of r.childNodes) { // Access all cells in row 'r'
      c.style.backgroundColor = "blue" // Change the background of all cells in row 'r'
    }
  }
}
```

The way the program ran made it so when I would click on a table, row `r` held the value of the last row in the table, making it such that if row `r` were to be changed in the event listener, it would only be changing the last row.

It took me hours to figure out, but the solution was to change the loop from `var r` to `let r`:

```
for (let r of table.childNodes[0].childNodes) {
  r.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // Do Stuff To Row 'r'
    for (var c of r.childNodes) { // Access all cells in row 'r'
      c.style.backgroundColor = "blue" // Change the background of all cells in row 'r'
    }
  }
}
```